# (Solution verification) Find the integral of the function $f(x,y,z)=xy$ over the region $R$ bounded by $x^2 + y^2=1, z=0, z=1, x\geq 0 , y \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> Find the integral of the function $f(x,y,z)=xy$ over the region $R$ bounded by $x^2 + y^2=1, z=0, z=1, x\geq 0 , y \geq 0$

Attempt: It is quite apparent we ought to use cylindrical coordinates. In this case, we obtain that $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $0\leq z \leq 1$. For the $\theta$ boundaries, we have that $\cos\theta \geq 0$ and that $\sin \theta \geq 0$ since $0 \leq r$. For this to be the case, we require that $0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, however as you will soon see, I suspect that is is incorrect. Expressing the integral, we have that:
$$\iiint_{R} xy dV=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int_{0}^1dr\int_{0}^1r^3\cos\theta\sin\theta dz=\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{2\theta}d\theta=0$$
Where did I make the mistake? Or this correct?

Comment: You almost did everything correct. Only the final integral should =1, not 0. Thus the answer is 1/8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By continuing your effort we have:
$$\frac 1 8 \int_0^{\frac {\pi} 2}\sin(2θ)dθ=\frac 1 8 \Big[ -\frac {\cos(2θ)} 2\Big]_0^{ \frac {\pi } 2}=\frac 1 8 $$